# Why I can't use background image in scss when I use webpack.js?

Tags: sass, webpack

I use webpack.js for build project:
jade/scss/js/node.js
My SCSS will be compiled to CSS:

```
 //SCSS
    .heading {
     background: url("/img/bg.png");
    }

  //CSS
   .heading {
   background- image:url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,...');
```

image is available on url: http://localhost:3000/img/bg.png

But it's not displaying as background-image.
I know that I should use url/file-loader to include images in css 
next config works, but I can't use images in scss/css files

```
{
 entry: "./src/js/main.js",
 devtool: "source-map",
 output: {
  path: __dirname + "/public",
  filename: "bundle.js"
},
module: {
  loaders: [
   {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loaders: ["style", "css"]
   },
   {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: ["style", "css?sourceMap", "sass?sourceMap"]
   },
   {
    test: /\.png$/,
    loaders: ["url-loader", "file-loader?sourceMap"]
   }
 ]
 }
}
```

Comment: If you're not getting the result you expected, you need to show the Sass code and the compiled results.

Comment: I added contents of my SCSS and CSS

Comment: Is that the actual output?  Because a space in there in background-image is invalid.  Also, that is the completely wrong mime type for a png.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an additional loader like [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-url-loader)  `sass-loader` has some [known issues with resolving URLs](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader/issues/144) in the past so this may be a solution for you.